# Categorical Confusion in Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra Second Edition

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*, exercise 6.45 (ii) in the second edition, he gives us objects $X, C_1, C_2$ and morphisms $g_1: X \rightarrow C_1$, $g_2: X \rightarrow C_2$, and asks us to prove the existence of a unique morphism $(g_1,g_2): X\rightarrow C_1\sqcap C_2$ which commutes with the projections. He then gives a hint about generalizing the diagonal map.

I'm confused because the map $(g_1,g_2)$ seems to be exactly the unique map guaranteed by the universal property of products, which is discussed at length in the preceding chapter. Am I missing something?

Comment: What category are these objects in? It sounds like he's asking you to prove the existence of products (in the universal sense) in a particular category where you have some idea of what the object $C_1\sqcap C_2$ should be.

Comment: Please provide more background (I don't have the book). What is $C_1 \sqcap C_2$?

Comment: There is no particular category. Rotman says to prove this in a category where $C_1\sqcap C_2$ (the product of $C_1$ and $C_2$) exists.

Comment: @thyde641: so you are right, it is exactly the universal property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition:** Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category, and let $C_1,C_2\in\mathbf{C}$ be its objects. Object $P\in\mathbf{C}$ called a *product of $C_1$ and $C_2$* if there exist two morphisms $p_1\colon P\to C_1$ and $p_2\colon P\to C_2$, such that for any object $X\in\mathbf{C}$ and for any two morphisms $g_1\colon X\to C_1$ and $g_2\colon X\to C_2$ there exists a unique morphism $(g_1,g_2)\colon X\to P$, such that $p_1\circ(g_1,g_2)=g_1$ and $p_2\circ(g_1,g_2)=g_2$. In this situation denote $P:=C_1\sqcap C_2$(more often $C_1\times C_2$). Existance of the morphism $(g_1,g_2)$ often called a *universal property of product*.

So I think that you are not missing anything. For greater certainty, see [nLab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/product).